# Que el cliente visualice website según su idioma

Tags: php, joomla3

Tengo un Joomla 3.4 multi-idioma que de momento sólo tiene 2 idiomas:

1. mi-dominio.com/es/
2. mi-dominio.com/en/

**OBJETIVO.** Que el cliente vea el website según su idioma.

**CÓMO HACERLO.** Lo que se me ocurrió fue intentar redirigir al visitante a la versión EN/ES según su IP (para ello empleo [esta librería](http://chir.ag/projects/geoiploc/)).

**PROBLEMA.** No habría ningún problema en hacer lo anterior si la redirección se hiciera en un index.php y redirigiera a index-es.php o a index-en.php. Pero en Joomla no existen index para cada idioma, sólo existe un index.php para todo.
Por tanto, el problema es que si hago un header:location dentro del index.php para que redirija a mi-dominio.com/es/ esto funciona, pero evidentemente cuando entre a mi-dominio.com/es/ se leerá nuevamente el index.php y por tanto se leerá nuevamente la redirección, y por consiguiente esto provoca un bucle infinito que causa que el website no se cargue nunca por el intento de múltiples redirecciones.

Este es el código que uso:

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION["pais_cliente"]) ) {
    $_SESSION["pais_cliente"] = getCountryFromIP($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
    $pais_cliente = $_SESSION["pais_cliente"];
    $_SESSION["num_redirecciones"] = 1;

    if ( ($pais_cliente == "EN") || ($pais_cliente == "UK") ) {
        header('Location: http://www.mi-dominio.com/en/');
    }
    else {
        header('Location: http://www.mi-dominio.com/es/');
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION["num_redirecciones"] ++;
    $pais_cliente = $_SESSION["pais_cliente"];

    if ( $_SESSION["num_redirecciones"] <= 2 ) {
        if ( ($pais_cliente == "EN") || ($pais_cliente == "UK") ) {
            header('Location: http://www.mi-dominio.com/en/');
        }
        else {
            header('Location: http://www.mi-dominio.com/es/');
        }
    }
}
```

Como verán, sólo permito que el bucle de redirecciones itere 2 veces máximo (para evitar el bucle infinito). Si visito la página por 3ra vez, evidentemente ya no se hace redirección y la página ya no me redirige a la versión en español o inglés según mi IP.

¿Alguna idea de cómo arreglar esto?

**Bienvenida cualquier idea para lograr que el visitante vea por default el website según su idioma, con o sin redirección, incluso con plugins para Joomla, mientras que sean gratuitos, claro!**

Comment: ¿cómo deseas determinar cuál es el "idioma" del usuario que te visita? Dices que se te ocurrió lo de la IP, pero no sé si es lo que consideras ideal o estás buscando otro método.

Comment: @Shaz Muchas gracias por responder. Han pasado ya unos días y me he quedado ya finalmente con esto (no digo que sea la mejor implementación pero funciona para lo que lo necesito): detecto el código de país mediante la ip mediante con la librería geoiploc.php. Con ella, simplemente creo una cookie (ya no uso sesiones). Si la cookie no existe redirijo al visitante a la versión EN/ES según su idioma; si la cookie ya existe no hago nada (con lo cual el visitante visualiza la versión EN/ES a la que fue redirigido antes)

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Porqué Detectar la **ip**, no sería mejor detectar el idioma del Navegador utilizado?... Yo podría vivir en *Suiza* y tener el navegador en *Español*.

**Joomla!** (no sé si desde la **1.7**) ya posee características *Multi-idioma* propias, no sería necesario en principio extensiones externas (aunque las hay como **Joomfish** que es un estupendo gestor multi-idioma).

En teoría sólo debes habilitar el plugin del sistema '*Filtrar idiomas*', digo 'en Teoría' porque la verdad es que se deben hacer varias cosas más, y la mayoría consisten en publicar contenido para cada lenguage; con contenido me refiero a '*Artículos*', '*Módulos*' y también a '*Menús*', realizar asociaciones, ... La verdad es que cuesta bastante trabajo hasta que se consigue. (Puedes conseguir información más detallada por ejemplo en: [Multi-Idioma Joomla 2.5](http://multilingual.demojoomla.com/es/multiidioma-paso-a-paso.html) (no importa que sea la 2.5))

Lo interesante es que este plugin posee un parámetro con el nombre "**Selección del idioma para visitantes nuevos**" donde tienes las opciones:

- Idioma del Sitio
- *Configuración del Navegador*

> Activa ésta última opción y no necesitarás la librería *geoiploc*

También hay otras opciones interesantes como: *Cambio automático del idioma*, *Asociación de elementos*, ...

OPINIÓN SUBJETIVA Y PERSONAL: Este sistema Multi-Lenguage supone una duplicidad de contenido pero es el sistema empleado por Joomla!, aunque en realidad tampoco habría muchas más opciones a no ser que se quisiera montar un sistema con traducción "*en tiempo real*" a través de herramientas online (http://translate.google.es)